# How to implement stretch animation in cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to give a stretch animation to a sprite .
     This is code i tried

```
id scaleUpAction =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo   actionWithDuration:4.0 scaleX:1.0 scaleY:10.0] rate:2.0];
```

But i want to keep the top position and then animate like wave effect from top to bottom.
Can any suggest me method to do this ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot understand what do you mean under "waves", but about first path of your question - to keep top position, you should change anchor point of your sprite. All transformations are done relatieve to the node's (sprite's in your case) anchor point. So, if you want to fix left-top corner of your sprite, just set it's `anchorPoint` property to (0.f, 1.f). Anchor point (1.f, 1.f) will fix right-top corner of your sprite.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this code.*

```
id scaleAction =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:5.0f scaleX:1.0 scaleY:1.0] rate:2.0];
id scaleUpAction =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1.0f scaleX:4.8 scaleY:4.8] rate:2.0];
id scaleUpAction1 =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:12 scaleX:4.8 scaleY:4.8] rate:2.0];
CCSequence *scaleSeq = [CCSequence actions:scaleAction,scaleUpAction,scaleUpAction1, nil];
[scaleright runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:scaleSeq]];
```